# WinSCP select most recent file

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

Looking for the WinSCP command line equivalent of selecting the most recent/latest file?
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file

I'm looking for a way to update my WinSCP command-line below to download the latest file:

```
winscp.com /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open sftp://martin@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx...""" "exit"
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest) of the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get), as the [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#scripting) article shows:

```
get -latest /home/user/* c:\downloaded\
```

---

If you want to use it on command-line, the syntax is like:

```
winscp.com /command "open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx...""" "get -latest /home/user/* c:\downloaded\" "exit"
```

Use [WinSCP GUI to generate command-line template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.