# Download most recent file of specific file name pattern from SFTP server using WinSCP in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp

I have to copy the most recent file with file mask `FileName_A_*` from SFTP location and place them in an sharedrive.

I tried using WinSCP. I have created an `Mostrecent.txt` file with below code and placed it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP`. Another batch file `Mostrecent.bat` to execute the script from `HourlyFile.txt`

`Mostrecent.txt`

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp..........
$source = '/outbound/test'
$destination = '\\sharedrive\'
@(Get-ChildItem $source -Filter FileName_A_* | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0] | % { Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination -force} 
exit
```

`Mostrecent.txt`

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp..........
$dir= '/outbound/test/FileName_A_*'
get  Dir | select -last 1 \\sharedrive
exit
```

The SFTP location will contain different files with different file name and extension. I need to just copy the most recent file with file pattern `FileName_A_*`. The file name will be:

```
FileName_A_20190619100000.txt
FileName_A_20190619110007.txt
FileName_A_20190619120040.txt
FileName_A_20190619130100.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PowerShell constructs in WinSCP script.

WinSCP has built-in functionality to download the latest file: [the `-latest` switch of the `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest).

So your `Mostrecent.txt` file can be:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://..........
get -latest /outbound/test/FileName_A_* \\sharedrive\
exit
```

---

See also:

- WinSCP article [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#scripting)
- Question [WinSCP select most recent file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22388746/850848)